# What is a reverse of a hash?

Tags: hash, mapping, reverse

The purpose of a hash is to take a unique blob and create a short unique identifier for it. Essentially we want to avoid collision

```
hash('test1') => 4r3oi34
hash('test2') => xkfo302
```

What would the opposite be - namely trying to achieve collision? Is there a name for mapping things in that way? Is it still considered a hash?

```
mapthingy('test1') => 12342
mapthingy('test2') => 12342
```

P.S. I tried asking the question at softwareengineering exchange but apparently I'm banned from asking questions.

Comment: like `mapthingy(){ return 12345;}`? Why should this be a hash why should it be anything at all?

Comment: @KamiKaze that is a pretty simplified example. What if `mapthingy` actually does a calculation similar to a hash? An example would be to map 1000 digits into 10 digits..

Comment: Well I do not understand the objective. You either want collisions or you don't or do you want them just sometimes? What are the requirements? Why would you want collisions and when do you want them?

Comment: @KamiKaze this is an existing implementation for "bucketing" data into smaller slots. I'm simply looking for a proper naming and definitions for this sort of thing. Is it still considered a hash? etc.

Comment: I am confused, so is the algo trying to get collisions or ist just that collisions are not considered that bad. The 2nd thing would still be hash but a bad one, it could be combined with error correction so CRC would fit this? The first one I can not say.